# Why Getting (user.models.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.)?

Tags: python, django

I have create two models CustomUser inheriting AbstractUser and UserProfile, and there is OneToOne relation between them.

**then i run the following command:-**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

When i run the command for createsuperuser, i got error as bellow:-(***model are posted in the end..***)

```
PS C:\Users\akcai\OneDrive\Desktop\deep_Stuffs\git_cloned\PollingApplication> python manage.py createsuperuser
Email: admin@gmail.com
Name: admin
Username: admin
Password:
Password (again):
The password is too similar to the username.
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
profile create too..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akcai\OneDrive\Desktop\deep_Stuffs\git_cloned\PollingApplication\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\akcai\OneDrive\Desktop\deep_Stuffs\git_cloned\PollingApplication\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 163, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 146, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 774, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\akcai\OneDrive\Desktop\deep_Stuffs\git_cloned\PollingApplication\user\models.py", line 27, in CreateProfile
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=instance)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\akcai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
user.models.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.
PS C:\Users\akcai\OneDrive\Desktop\deep_Stuffs\git_cloned\PollingApplication>
```

**models.py:-**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
                                         
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'username']


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_all_polls(self):
        from polls.models import PollQuestion
        pass


def CreateProfile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("profile create too..")
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=instance)
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)


post_save.connect(CreateProfile, sender=CustomUser)
# following = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, symmetrical=False, null=True)
```

after this i tried to login to admin portal and get:- `CustomUser matching query does not exist.`

After this i checked the db is there any user exist or not:-

```
>>> from user.models import CustomUser
>>> u = CustomUser.objects.get(id=1)
>>> vars(u)
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000001C3C5B4CCA0>, 'id': 1, 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 21, 6, 43, 56, 565960, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'is_superuser': True, 'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'is_staff': True, 'is_active': True, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 21, 6, 28, 44, 123074, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'email': 'admin@gmail.com', 'name': 'admin', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$260000$SP9TyZ6VOMIFlRwvuvmDn4$7sak8fWf7QMTPfefoPMyQpLjYk3XpumRaJ5MMxq2lH4='}
>>>
```

I am unable to figure out on my own, what i am doing wrong, please help to get out of this rid.

Hope to here from you soon..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=instance)
```

makes little sense.

You're trying to get an user by querying whether their username equals an instance (of CustomUser).

This will cause Django to stringify the CustomUser, so your query ends up something like (if SQL were Python)

```
if username == "<CustomUser: 3>":
```

which obviously will yield no rows.

In general, you should not need both [a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) **and** [a user profile model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). Maybe rethink your database models so you only have your custom user model, and be sure to use the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to wire it up.

Comment: I have added AUTH_USER_MODEL in setting.py..

Comment: Great. Then you don't need the separate UserProfile model at all.

Comment: @AKK i did't understand, can you please if i have added AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py then i don't have to create seprate profie model why?

Comment: Because your custom user model can already contain the additional fields (and methods) you'd want in your profile model.